# How to write integral to calculate the area where a field is between two limits?

Tags: magnetic-fields, integration

I would like to express the following quantity in a mathematical form, but cannot think how I would write the integral.

"The area on the surface of a cylinder where the magnetic field is between two limits, say, -∞ and -15 nt"

I attempted to write

$\int_{-∞}^{\theta(B)=-15\mathrm{nT}}\int_{-∞}^{z(B)=-15\mathrm{nT}}\vec{B}\cdot d\theta dz = A$

but I'm not too sure on the limit values. As you can see from the figure, the shape is curved, and doesn't have sides with constant values of $\theta$ or $z$, so I'm not certain how one would express the integral limits.

Top left: plot of the magnetic field on the surface

Top right: Field between two limits. **It is the area of this shape that I want to express mathematically.**

Bottom: showing how I compute the integral within the program.

[image]

Comment: the limits of the integral needs to be in terms of its differentials. in the given integral above $dz$ and $d\theta$

Comment: I don't really know what you're trying to do, but like @linuxick said, you should find the coordinates $d\theta$ and $dz$ where B=a and B=b to integrate.

Comment: @QuirkyTurtle98 thanks for the responses, I have added a diagram to explain more clearly what I am trying to express. Ideally I'd like to explain mathematically that I calculate the surface area of the shape in the top right image.